# How to vertically align picture in line using python-docx

Tags: python-docx

I am adding a picture (some latex converted into a PNG using matplotlib) to my text using the following code:

```
par = doc.add_paragraph()
par.add_run().text = 'foo bar baz'
par.add_run().add_picture('pic.png')
par.add_run().text = 'blah blah blah'
```

This works OK, except that the picture `pic.png` is not vertically aligned in the rest of the text in the document:

[image: raised]

I can get the alignment manually in MS Word by adding a character style with the advanced vertical alignment property set to "lowered by 10pt":

[image: fixed]

The problem is that I have no idea how to do this programatically using python-docx. Conceptually the steps would be to compute the size of the image, create a character style that was lowered by half that size minus half the size of the font and apply the style to the run containing the picture. How do you create a raised or lowered font style in python-docx?

For reference, here is `pic.png`: [image: pic.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image has a fairly large (transparent) border around it. I added a single pixel border inside its extents here to make it visible:

[image]

I expect Word is aligning the bottom of the image with the baseline (as expected). One approach would be to see if there was a way you could specify zero bottom border.

You could also try subscript on that image run. I'm not sure what it would do but it's worth a try. So something like this:

```
run = par.add_run()
run.add_picture('x.png')
run.font.subscript = True
```

If you find the run that you manually set to "lowered by 10pt", you can view the XML for it like this (aircode):

```
run = vertically_adjusted_run()  # however you get ahold of it
print(run._element.xml)
```

I expect you'll see something like this:

```
<w:r>
  <w:rPr>
    <w:position w:val="20"/>
    ...
```

... where the w:position element sets the adjustment from the baseline. The value is specified in half-points.

Anyway, neither this adjustment nor even that low-level element are supported by python-docx yet, so you'd need to get in there with lxml calls to do the needful if you wanted it badly enough.

Comment: I was expecting to have to edit the XML. Thanks for the pointer. Is the python-docx Google mailing list a good place to ask for help once I have figured out the relevant XML? Also, would you like me to open an issue on GitHub for now, and possibly a PR later if I can get this working properly?

Comment: Actually here is probably the best place to get support answers, just make sure you tag your question with 'python-docx' so it shows up in the RSS feed. If it comes down to a feature request, the GitHub issue list is the place. You could check there to see if there's already an open feature request then +1 if yes or add one if no. Pasting a working solution into the issue is often best for this sort of thing. A pull request isn't likely to be successful without an enhancement proposal (aka. analysis page) and both acceptance and unit tests.

Comment: You can look at the tops of the feature/header and feature/tabstops branches to get an idea what's involved in a succesful pull request :)

Comment: Thanks @scanny. I think I have the XML nailed down. I will try to write a PR to lower the font relative to the text baseline via a settable property.